# Spring 3 scheduled with fixedRate seems to stops executing unexpectedly after certain point, how to debug?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task in Spring 3.2.4 web application that is scheduled to run with a fixedRate of 1 minute. After a day or so, the task stops executing, but it's not predictable when will it happen so I failed to reproduce this in my development environment.

I tried collecting a thread dump after this happens to have a clue where it stopped, however, if I interpreted thread dump correctly, the threads are not blocked in my code.

Sample of the output of thread dump looks like this (there's a dump like that for each thread in the thread pool):

```
Thread 5510: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=196 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) @bci=68, line=2025 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take() @bci=57, line=164 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=4, line=609 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take() @bci=1, line=602 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=78, line=947 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=18, line=907 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)
```

To me, this looks normal - threads waiting in the pool.

My question is how do I go about debugging this further? Is there a way to somehow access and dump information about spring scheduling state in the runtime (e.g. next execution time, last execution time, which jobs are executing, how many free threads are in the thread pool etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a thread dump again, immediately after the issue happened, I found the cause - scheduled task had an infinite loop that could happen in certain conditions.

For future reference thread dump was taken with:

```
jstack [process id] > threaddump.txt
```

I managed to solve the problem though I still don't quite understand why problematic infinite loop didn't appear in thread dumps that were taken few hours after the issue occured.